# jQuery: Hide Show div when checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I want a div to be hidden when the page load and then if a checkbox is checked, show the div and then hide again when it is unchecked.

.checkCover is the checkbox and #show_coversheet is the div.

What is wrong with the below code?

```
$(function () {
  $('.checkCover').change(function () {                
     $('#show_coversheet').toggle(!this.unchecked);
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the ! before this.checked

```
$('.checkCover').change(function () {                
    $('#show_coversheet').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 3):

`unchecked` is not a property, but `checked` is!

```
$('.checkCover').change(function () {                
    $('#show_coversheet').toggle(!this.checked);
}).change();
```

Comment: i've tried that, but that is opposite of what I want. I want checked to show the div.

Comment: @user3108698 -- Put a `!` in front of the `this.checked` call then